# J2EE, Spring, Hibernate-multimodule, maven, jboss in ubuntu

Tags: linux, spring, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

We are using to develop J2EE applications in Ubuntu 14.04(also tried fedora 21). Our technology stack include - Java, Spring, Hibernate, maven as build tool, mysql  and JBoss as application server.

The issue is that while building and deploying consecutive times, the OS got stuck. Restarting the PC is the only choice to go out from this. The issue occurs both in fedora and Ubuntu while Windows 8 or any Windows OS runs smoothly.We have around 20 developers here so cannot afford paid version of windows.

Is there any OS that we can run smoothly with our the technology stack i mentioned above since, most of our time is get around on restarting the PC.

Comment: Do you check the Java runtime? Problem might come from your java runtime. Currently I am working with Ubuntu 14.04, OpenJDK 7 and everything work well. Do you use IDE for build and deploy local? If yes, the problem might come from that too.

Comment: OS will hang while deploying to jboss - occurs mostly in maven connecting to jboss after packaging. Nothing can be done at this time.